# React JS: display map components as flex style in the same row

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sass

I am learning React js and trying to build a product page of an E-commerce website, but I am stuck with the part where I should put the map components from a data in the same row. Here is the link for my codes.

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-glade-dvps24?file=/src/Shop.scss

What I want is to put three products in a row, but it seems like if you map an item the whole wrappers will be duplicated since they are map components. Any helps would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the wrapper outside the map. I usually set the wrapper styling to `display: grid;`
Check my changes:
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-voice-pf8pst?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think it works but why there's a space on the right? I tried 0 margin and padding, and width 100%, but it's still the same.

Comment: It is because you set the card width to 300px making the first row at least 900px. It overflows the body which is (in my screen) around 600px. If you need the fixed width of 300 you need to adjust the grid to display 1 or 2 cards depending on your body width. I can recommend you look into breakpoints if you want to dynamically change the number of cards on each row. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp